# Can phonegap app download through internet by runtime?

Tags: cordova

I have some problem with app using phonegap
Some tutorial teach that put js and lib in project (my situation is android)
and my html app in `assets/www`

Question 1.
  Is it possible to load html by runtime
  [ex. my app load an url on the internet(ex: http://mobilegwt.appspot.com/showcase/ ) ]
  I'll put phonegap's js and lib in the android app
  and only load the web app using url

Question 2.
  If it can. Then how can I load the phonegap's js in order to use function of phonegap

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot. cordova functioning only on device, not in web app.